# ANYLOGIC Seize Resources

Tags: anylogic

I would like the agent from source 1 to use tool1 and tool2. What code should I write in seize block in order to achieve it?

[As seen in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlKP3.png)

Answer (score 0):

None. You setup the seize object to use both in a way that you require. You can seize from several resource pools directly using the Seize properties.

The [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2F_ProcessModeling%2FUsing_Resources.html) is your friend:
[image]